# Where's this lookout over cherry blossoms and town on top of hummock, surrounded by other knolls, in Yoshino, Japan?

Tags: japan, identify-this

### Pic 1 on [reddit](https://redd.it/612hwq)

I already tried Google Reverse Image Search. I don't want just fish, but teach me how to fish! If you never went here, pls expound how you located.

Can I drive and just step out car to look out? I don't want to hike! Or did drone photo-graph this?

[image]

#### Pic 2 on [reddit](https://redd.it/dhzr7e)

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've never been there.

1. I loaded Google Earth.
2. I typed in Yoshino, Japan (which is in your question title).
3. I saw that the town and some of the surrounding areas are built in valleys. Your picture shows a town on a ridge, so I knew I didn't have to look in the valleys.
4. I found a nearby town (which I saw is called Yoshinoyama) on a ridge which happened to have a large building shaped very much like the one in your photos. (That building turns out to be a temple called [Kimpusen-ji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kimpusen-ji).)
5. After some adjustment of viewing angle, I got the following view:

[image: Yoshinoyama]

Answer (score 5):

I have been there twice. It is a beautiful place, well worth a visit.

You can get there by car, and you can get views like the ones above from (or at least very near) driveable roads.

However, Yoshino is *very* popular -- especially when the cherry blossoms are in bloom, as they are in your photos. Traffic, including heavy foot traffic, will be a major annoyance. Parking is also likely to be difficult, perhaps impossible without an inn reservation. You won't be able to just "step out of your car".

If possible, I'd recommend arriving at the Yoshino train station and then walking up the mountain. The roads are paved, and there is also a ropeway covering the steepest part. It is not a particularly arduous walk.